# Object compare using Hash Code-Concept dilemma

Tags: c#

I have written a piece of code to check for Object Equality.
I took refrence from one of the question in stack overflow itself.
Now this code is giving true even if we have two different objects.
Can someone explain why?

```
using System;
namespace ConsolePractice
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string String1 { get; set; }
        public string String2 { get; set; }



        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hash = 19;
            hash = hash * 31 + Value;
            hash = hash * 31 + String1.SafeGetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + String2.SafeGetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Test test = obj as Test;
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return Value == test.Value &&
                String1 == test.String1 &&
                String2 == test.String2;
        }
    }

    class Demo
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Test p1 = new Test
            {
                Value = 10,
                String1 = "Test1",
                String2 = "Test2"
            };
            Test p2 = new Test
            {
                Value = 10,
                String1 = "Test1",
                String2 = "Test2"
            };
            bool areEqual = p1.Equals(p2);

            Console.WriteLine(areEqual.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

and in my `UtilityClass`

```
 static class utility
    {
        public static int SafeGetHashCode<T>(this T value) where T : class
        {
            return value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

After no success,i tried below code which also return true.
What blunder am I doing here?Please help

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;


class ThingEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Thing>
{
    public bool Equals(Thing x, Thing y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Thing obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}


public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
class Demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Thing p1 = new Thing
        {
            Id = 10,
            Name = "Test1",

        };
        Thing p2 = new Thing
        {
            Id = 10,
            Name = "Test1",

        };

        var comparer = new ThingEqualityComparer();
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(p1, p2));


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not expect this to return true?

Comment: I think `Test test = obj as Test; if (obj == null)` should have been `Test test = obj as Test; if (test == null)`

Comment: @JonHanna-Because These are different objects .I believe we need to override Equals for value equality and check every field.here two objects are different,is it not supposed to give false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to define what "equals" means in a given context.

Your `Equals` of:

```
Test test = obj as Test;
if (obj == null)
{
  return false;
}
return Value == test.Value &&
  String1 == test.String1 &&
  String2 == test.String2;
```

Has a bug in that it should be `if(test == null) return false;` but otherwise it says "two `Test` objects are the same if they have the same `Value`, `String1` and `String2`, otherwise they are not. Your `GetHashCode()` is consistent with that.

As such, it's not a bug to have the code return `true`:

> Now this code is giving true even if we have two different objects.

Yes, two different **equal** objects.

If you want `Equals` and `GetHashCode()` to tell you whether they are the **same** object or not (that is, for an object of a class to be equal only to itself) then don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` at all; stay with the default behaviour.

Comment: Got you point Sir..Just one more detail-If I need have one object(say o1) and other refrence (r1) to that  object o1(r1=o1),then i can check this by default Equals..So why we have AS operator and same by Icomaprarer interface?That too does same thing right?Please forgive my confusion

Comment: `as` gives us a reference of a different type: Say `object r1 = "abc"` then `string r2 = r1 as string` means `r2` is the same as `r1` but as a string, while `Uri r3 = r1 as Uri` means `r3` is `null` because `r1` wasn't a `Uri` so this couldn't work. `IComparer` lets us compare objects in an order. `IEqualityComparer` lets us set different rules for equality than those set by the `Equals` override, should we have a special case. E.g. `string` has an `Equals` that returns true if two strings are exactly the same characters in same order but there are `IEqualityComparers` for case-insensitive etc

Comment: `ReferenceEquals` lets us tell if two equal objects are actually the same object or not. (Doing a matching `GetHashCode()` for that is tricky. Luckily it's rarely necessary but https://www.nuget.org/packages/AisA/ can be used in the very rare cases where we care).

Comment: @asawyer thanks a lot.IS operator also comapres two objects.Why cant we use this one.This is  last piece of my confusion.

Comment: `is` also does **not** compare two objects. It tells use if an object is of a type; `"abc" is string` returns `true`, `"abc" is int` returns false. `"abc" is "abc"` (comparing two objects) does not compile and is not allowed. `T y = x as T` is the much the same as `T y = (x is T) ? (T)x : null` but only checks the type once.

Comment: (The Visual Basic.NET `Is` Operator does compare two objects, but it is completely different to the C# `is` operator).